# Angular template array interpolation

Tags: arrays, angular, data-binding, interpolation

I'm trying to render an array of strings in a template with double curly braces.

Additionally I have a button that, when clicked, adds another string to the array.

Why is `{{ myarray }}` never updated after clicking the button, but `{{ myarray.length }}` is?

I did a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/carlosromerob/pen/vYyXEQY?editors=1111).

Comment: I’m surprised the initial value renders. Try this: <p>{{ myarray | json }}</p>

Comment: @MikeOne hah, that works. How come, surprised?

Comment: Because I would have expected it to print [Object object]..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is to use Object's prototype function `toString()` (even though MikeOne comment is great catch, usually `json()` is useful for debugging. And it will print you array with brackets).

`toString()` and `valueOf()` are two methods on Object's prototype, used to convert  values to primitive types (and `{{ }}` does exactly this - tries to convert your array into a primitive value. So it did render initial values, because `toString()` was called):

```
{{ myarray.toString() }}
```

And it prints array length change, because thats a primitive value.

Can read more about `toString()` and `valueOf()` [here](http://blog.marcinchwedczuk.pl/augmenting-JavaScript-objects-with-toString-and-valueOf)